# Session ID changing after logged in on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm making a cart system using the session_id of the client. My problem is that after logged in, this session_id is changing. I'm using Fortify on Laravel 8.x.

Do you know how can I preserve this session_id, or in other case, just get the new session_id after the logged in ? I don't find any method on Fortify that been called **after the login**.

Thanks you.

Comment: _“using the session_id of the client”_ - meaning what, exactly? You are using the session id as identifier, but you are not storing the actual cart data into the user session? If so, _why_? Either keep the cart in the user’s own session, or use a non-changing identifier, such as their user id.

Comment: Actually, I'm storing in the database the session_id for each cart. And doing a request like ->where session_id = session id of the current client. So you think the best way to do that is just to register the ID of the cart in the session and get this one when I need him ?

Comment: Yes, give the card data some auto-generated ID then, and store that into the session.

Comment: Thanks you. I've added this answer to the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for that is to change the structure of my actual code.

- **Do not save the session_id** in the database.
- **Save the cart_id** in the session.
  With this method, I can simply retrieve the actual cart for the session with all session id changes.

*Thanks to @CBroe for this answer.*

Comment: Can you explain this with an example?